# Bootstrap 3.3.4 carousel: left/right controls collides with smooth page scroll script

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, smooth-scrolling

The left and right controls script of my bootstrap carousel is colliding with the smooth page scroll script.

I did test another solution found in stackoverflow. The carousel worked, but the smooth page scroll did stop working.

The original working scroll:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')  && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 500);
      return false;
     }
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

The stackoverflow "solution" that breaks the smooth page scroll:

```
Change:

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

to (if you use the ID header-menu):

$('#header-menu a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

or (if you use the class header-menu):

$('.header-menu a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
```

The URL of the wrong solution: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840059/left-and-right-carousel-controls-not-working-when-smooth-scroll-for-anchor-tags)

I'd like to know how to make both the carousel and the smooth scoll works at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I did find this solution just in Stackoverflow.

Change:

```
 $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
```

to:

```
 $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not(.carousel-control)').click(function () {
```

The solution is a comment so it WAS NEVER MARKED as the correct one. Here is the topic:

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046956/smooth-scrolling-issue)